# How to load data from the database. UID-inform

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase, but when I click the button, I put the data I entered into the Firebase. I want to show the data I have input by bringing in the input data when the setting window is displayed
Maybe I have to write it after setting the data in the DTO.

I do not want the recycle view, but I want to load the data when I go to the configuration window class. I get an error when loading five objects separately.

```
myRef = database.getReference("User");  
myRef.child(tmpStr).addListenerForSingleValueEvent
(new ValueEventListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) 
    {
                chat = singleSnapshot.getValue(ChatData.class);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e("onCancelled", 
String.valueOf(databaseError.toException()));
        }
});
```

[image: my firebasedata]

[MY ChatDTO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOwlN.png)

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: I solved it myself. It was an incorrect index error. Thank you